# c# Response.Write and End() Json String to long

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, webforms

I'm trying to output a 'very long' Json string when i save this file on ondisk it is 405KB but i want to serve it to the client with Response.Write but that doesn't output for some strange reason and the string is filled.
This is a Simple ASP.NET Webpage no MVC
when i use

```
    // Clear out the buffer
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Clear();

    // Do not cache response
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

    // Set the content type and encoding for JSON
    Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Response.Write(strJsonData);

    // Flush the response buffer
    Response.Flush();

    // Complete the request.  NOTE: Do not use Response.End() here,
    // because it throws a ThreadAbortException, which cannot be caught!
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

it won't put the response on my screen.

What i tried:
Web.config

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength ="999999999" requestValidationMode="2.0" />

<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="999999999" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: What's the error message? `Response.Write` is about outgoing, `requestLimits` is about incoming data

Comment: What does `ondisk` mean? That you want to save the string on the server? Or do you actually mean that you want to send a Json result to the client?

Comment: I mean that the file itselfs when i save it ondisk 405kb is but i want to response it to the client with Response.Write But it doesnt work but JsonResult is filled.

Comment: What kind of web site is this? Web forms, MVC? What is `JsonResult`? Is it your string's name? Does it have any content? How did you fill it?

Comment: Exaclty fubo but the string is filled with the correct Serialized JSON Data

Comment: @fubo asp.net doesn't mean webforms, in fact the tag descriptions explains that the proper type tag should be used. Just hover over the tag

Comment: please copy and paste the entire controller's method

Comment: IT IS NO CONTROLLER its WebForms

Comment: Im using Chrome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request length limits the length request that goes to the server, not the response.

Try this in the Web.config:

```html
<configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="99999999"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Im gonna try it out